# I have writtten code to check if there is even one entry in database to give message duplicate entry

Tags: codeigniter

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#save_btn").click(function(){
            kabina=jQuery("#d_id").val();
            var city = $('.city option:selected').map(function(idx, elem) {
            return $(elem).html();
            }).get();//alert(city);
            //city=jQuery("#ct_title").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php  echo $menulink;?>/checkunique',
                data:{city:city,kabina:kabina},
                success:function(data){
                    //alert(data);
                    if(data == 'True')
                    {
                        toastr.success("Building Created",'Attention',{"positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width" });
                        $("#city_frm").submit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toastr.error("Building Created",'Attention',{"positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width" });
                        $("#city_frm").submit();
                    }
                    //alert(data);
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Here is the ajax from which the controller check unique method is called
This is the controller

```
public function checkunique(){
        $count=array();
        if(isset($_POST['kabina'])){
            //$ct_id = $_POST['ct_id'];
            $kabina = $_POST['kabina'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];//print_r($city);

            foreach($city as $ct_title)
            {//print_r($ct_title);
            $ct_count=$this->mod_atyatbox_cities->city_count($ct_title,$kabina);//print_r($ct_count);die;;
                $count[]=$ct_count;
            }//print_r($count);die;
            if(in_array(1,$count))
            {
                echo "False";
            }
            else if(in_array(0,$count))
            {
                echo "True";
            }
}
```

Here is teh model where query is wrote to check for duplicate entry

```
function city_count($ct_title,$kabina_id)
{
    $query="select ct_title from city where ct_title='$ct_title' and kabina_id=$kabina_id";
    $result=$this->db->query($query)->num_rows();//echo $result;die;
    return $result;
}
```

Here if I print the query it prints. But when I return the data it returns 0 even if there is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the query from the array

```
foreach($city as $ct_title){
    $ct_count=$this->mod_atyatbox_cities->city_count($ct_title,$kabina);
    $count[]=$ct_count;
    $queries[]=$this->db->last_query();
}
print_r($queries);die;
```